# Performance issues with pulsating icon animation in .NET 7 MAUI Blazor application

Tags: .net, event-handling, blazor, css-animations, maui-blazor

I am developing a .NET 7 MAUI Blazor application that connects to a Wi-Fi device, which sends a "SignOfLife" signal to my client every second when the connection is active. The connection is using UDP. In my "Receive" thread, I parse the received data and check if it corresponds to a "SignOfLife" signal (based on a specific byte sequence). When a "SignOfLife" signal is received, I raise a "SignOfLifeReceived" event. In my Index.razor component, I subscribe to the "SignOfLifeReceived" event and use "InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)" there. The visualization is achieved by pulsating a heart icon. To do this, I bind the CSS class of the icon to the "GetClassForUDPDeviceIcon" method, which returns "me-2 pulsing-icon". The CSS for the animation is as follows:

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.pulsing-icon {
    animation: pulse 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

However, this approach seems to cause severe lag and performance issues. The user interface becomes unresponsive and reacts very slowly. I suspect that the frequent invocation of "StateHasChanged" is the main cause. However, I only want to visualize actually received data, so I cannot simply set the "animation-iteration-count" to "infinite".

My question in summary:

Question: How can I improve the performance of a .NET 7 MAUI Blazor application that uses a pulsating icon animation to visualize received data from a UDP-connected Wi-Fi device, without causing significant lag and unresponsiveness in the user interface?